# android slow interface on zenfone 5

Tags: android, performance

I'm developing app in android studio using standard android interface. 
Problem is that all interface is very laggy on Asus zenfone 5. Listviews scroll very slow and freezy, animation (rotation, translation) also very slow and laggy. At my neighbors Nexus 5 all is fine, in emulator all also fine. But on my zenfone are problems. May be it because of Intel chip set?

Comment: what about stock apps like gmail, play store ?

Comment: they work perfectly, smooth and fast